# extract edge features with prewitt_h

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-learn, scikit-image, image-classification

I am trying to extract edge features like this:

```
img = io.imread('pic.jpg')

H, W, C = img.shape

features = custom_features(img)
assignments = kmeans_fast(features, num_segments)

segments = assignments.reshape((H, W))

# Display segmentation
plt.imshow(segments, cmap='viridis')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

custom_features:

```
from skimage.filters import prewitt_h,prewitt_v

def custom_features(image):
    """ 

    Args:
        img - array of shape (H, W, C)

    Returns:
        features - array of (H * W, C)
    """

    edges_prewitt_horizontal = prewitt_h(image)

    return edges_prewitt_horizontal
```

However, currently I get an error because the shape of the image is different than what is expected by the `prewitt_h` function.

```
ValueError: The parameter `image` must be a 2-dimensional array
```

How can I modify this inside the function such that the returned shape is as desired?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to give to prewitt a grayscale image. The prewitt transform applies a convolution with a 2-dimensional kernel, hence you need 2-dimensional image (and yours is 3-d, because you have colors (RGB, 3 Channels)).

You could add inside your `custom_features` method a conversion to grayscale (`skimage` that you are using already has a method for that, [check it out](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_rgb_to_gray.html) )

```
from skimage.filters import prewitt_h,prewitt_v
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

def custom_features(image):
    """ 

    Args:
        image - array of shape (H, W, C)

    Returns:
        features - array of (H * W, C)
    """
    grayscale = rgb2gray(image)
    edges_prewitt_horizontal = prewitt_h(grayscale)

    return edges_prewitt_horizontal
```

And this should do the trick (I assume the image that the `custom_features` methods receives in input is always an RGB image because of the shape you defined above).
In case you have different types you can add a check `if C == 3:` to convert only RGB images.

Comment: This seems to fix one problem. However, now when I reach ```segments = assignments.reshape((H, W))``` part, I get an error again because ```ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 399 into shape (399,624)
```

Comment: That is another problem. I think we need more information. Can you tell us or add in the code what `kmeans_fast` (or which library you take it from) is and which value you used for `num_segments` ? It looks like those are not aligned. From your error it seems `assignment` is a 1D array.

Comment: ```num_segments``` used is 8. ```kmeans_fast``` is the general kmeansFast algorithm. It returns ```assignments``` that is an ```array representing cluster assignment of each point. (e.g. i-th point is assigned to cluster assignments[i])```

Comment: The shape of ```features``` returned by the ```custom_features``` function is ```(399, 624)```. Segments were basically used for displaying the image. Perhaps another way could be used?

Comment: yes, the prewitt method outputs the edge map (an image). I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain in details in which form you want your edge features to be? The features is an image map (edge are given through pixel intensities), while k-means works with points (x,y). Later you convert it back to an image shape to visualize it. This is confusing. Are you maybe looking for something like [label](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/scikit-image/auto_examples/plot_labels.html#sphx-glr-packages-scikit-image-auto-examples-plot-labels-py) to color the different segmented parts?

Comment: If I use ```plt.imshow(features, cmap='viridis')```, it works. However, I want to visualize it after applying kmeans. Hence, I am trying ```plt.imshow(segments, cmap='viridis')```

Answer (score 0):

By default, skimage.io.imread returns the read JPEG image as a shape-(M, N, 3) array, representing an RGB color image. However, the prewitt functions expect that the input is a single channel image.

To fix this, convert the image to grayscale first with [skimage.color.rgb2gray](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html?highlight=gray#skimage.color.rgb2gray) before filtering. Or you could read the image directly as grayscale with `skimage.io.imread(f, as_gray=True)`.